# Убрать все анонимные обработчики событий (Анонимные методы)

Tags: c#, события

Есть объект `BackgroundWorker`, к которому постоянно привязывается новое событие `DoWork`.

```
MainWindow.bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {
    e.Result = ///////;
});
```

Как, не создавая новый экземпляр класс `BackgroundWorker` можно отвязать от него анонимное (объявленное с помощью лямбда выражения) событие?

Comment: Сделать его именованным. Например, локальной функцией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DoWorkEventHandler handler = null;
handler = new DoWorkEventHandler((object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
{
    MainWindow.bw.DoWork -=handler;
     e.Result = ///////;
});
MainWindow.bw.DoWork +=handler;
```